# kubernetes to print specific columns

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, jsonpath, azure-aks, k8s-cronjobber

Need only specific columns using JSONPATH query in kubernetes:

- `$ kubectl get node`

```
NAME  STATUS    ROLES   AGE VERSION
1     Ready     master  35d v1.18.6
2     Ready     <none>  35d v1.18.6
3     Ready     <none>  35d v1.18.6             
4     Ready     <none>  35d v1.18.6             
5     Ready     master  35d v1.18.6             
6     Ready     <none>  35d v1.18.6
```

Desired output should look like this:

```
NAME    VERSION
1       v1.18.6
2       v1.18.6
3       v1.18.6
4       v1.18.6
5       v1.18.6 
6       v1.18.6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Th answer to above question is:

- `$ kubectl get node -o=jsonpath='{range.items[*]}{.metadata.selfLink} {"\t"} {.status.nodeInfo.kubeletVersion}{"\n"}{end}'`

It will produce output:

```sh
01    v1.18.6
02    v1.18.6
03    v1.18.6
04    v1.18.6
05    v1.18.6
```

For further sorting:

- `$ kubectl get node -o=custom-columns=NODE:.metadata.selfLink`
- `$ kubectl get node -o=custom-columns=VERSION:.status.nodeInfo.kubeletVersion`

  `kubectl get node -o=custom-columns=NODE:.metadata.selfLink,VERSION:.status.nodeInfo.kubeletVersion N`

Comment: I think you have a typo here. If you are looking for name of the node you should use: `.metadata.name` instead of `.metadata.selfLink`.

Comment: Not exactly .metadata.selfLink  gives complete path -->  """/api/v1/nodes/hostname01    v1.18.6"""
Where as .metadata.name gives only host list -->
"""hostname01          v1.18.6"""